# Any straightforward way of adding multiindex columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[80, 82, 81, 84], [100, 101, 98, 102]]).T, 
                  index=[0, 1, 2, 3], 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['weight'], ['Apple', 'Orange']]))

  weight       
   Apple Orange
0     80    100
1     82    101
2     81     98
3     84    102
```

I would like to put their .diff() into a new column, but I cannot achieve that naturally like working with a simple df with single-level columns:

```
# 1st try:
df['diff'] = df['weight'].diff()

KeyError: 'diff'
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

```
# 2nd try:
df[['diff']] = df[['weight']].diff()

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

```
# 3rd try:
df = df.join(df[['weight']].diff().rename(columns={'weight':'diff'}))

  weight         diff       
   Apple Orange Apple Orange
0     80    100   NaN    NaN
1     82    101   2.0    1.0
2     81     98  -1.0   -3.0
3     84    102   3.0    4.0
```

The 3rd try works but it seems so unnatural to me.
I assume there is a more straightforward way to add multiindex columns without doing renaming columns and join, merge or concat?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to avoid using column names that have similar pandas function. ex: diff. You may struggle later to figure out if its a column or a function you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
In [3301]: x = df.diff()

In [3321]: x.columns = x.columns.set_levels(['diff'], level=0)

In [3324]: pd.concat([df, x], 1)
Out[3324]: 
  weight         diff       
   Apple Orange Apple Orange
0     80    100   NaN    NaN
1     82    101   2.0    1.0
2     81     98  -1.0   -3.0
3     84    102   3.0    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not create a new multiindex column named 'diff'.

Comment: @Jumiao Updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

`df.diff()` returns a dataframe, if it would return a Series then you could easily assign as a column, otherwise you need to `.join()` or `.concat()`